# JBoss EAP 6.4 JMX queryMBeans filtering doesn't work

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, jboss6.x, mbeans

I am running the following query against JBoss 6.4 standalone-full configuration but the filtering doens't work. The result is that all the MBeans are retrieved by the query and the filter is not applied.

```
mBeanServer.queryMBeans(null, Query.isInstanceOf(Query.value(className)));
```

Is there a way to avoid that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found , it's a bug of jmx module https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-1257?devStatusDetailDialog=pullrequest <BR> So i am looking for a workaound in my code